Unable to import PyTorch in Jetson nano using Docker image
I have trouble importing PyTorch in my jetson nano (jetpack 4.4). I have successfully installed it from .whl file. please help.
==> Launching app...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/catkin_ws/src/duckietown-safe-ml-demo/packages/safe_ml/src/ood_node.py", line 13, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 290, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/lib/../../torch.libs/libgomp-804f19d4.so.1.0.0: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

I am able to build docker image successfully, but when I try to run image, at that time it says that this error.
please Help!!!
   # parameters
    ARG REPO_NAME="duckietown-safe-ml-demo"
    ARG DESCRIPTION="Safe ML on the Duckie Town Platform"
    ARG MAINTAINER="michaelj004@e.ntu.edu.sg"
    # pick an icon from: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/
    ARG ICON="cube"
    
    # ==================================================>
    # ==> Do not change the code below this line
    ARG ARCH=arm32v7
    ARG DISTRO=daffy
    ARG BASE_TAG=${DISTRO}-${ARCH}
    ARG BASE_IMAGE=dt-ros-commons
    ARG LAUNCHER=default
    
    # define base image
    FROM duckietown/${BASE_IMAGE}:${BASE_TAG} as BASE
    
    # Changed to have the full suite of DT-packages.
    #ARG AIDO_REGISTRY=docker.io
    #FROM ${AIDO_REGISTRY}/duckietown/dt-car-interface:${BASE_TAG} AS dt-car-interface
    #FROM ${AIDO_REGISTRY}/duckietown/dt-core:${BASE_TAG} AS base
    
    # recall all arguments
    ARG ARCH
    ARG DISTRO
    ARG REPO_NAME
    ARG DESCRIPTION
    ARG MAINTAINER
    ARG ICON
    ARG BASE_TAG
    ARG BASE_IMAGE
    ARG LAUNCHER
    
    # check build arguments
    RUN dt-build-env-check "${REPO_NAME}" "${MAINTAINER}" "${DESCRIPTION}"
    
    # define/create repository path
    ARG REPO_PATH="${CATKIN_WS_DIR}/src/${REPO_NAME}"
    ARG LAUNCH_PATH="${LAUNCH_DIR}/${REPO_NAME}"
    RUN mkdir -p "${REPO_PATH}"
    RUN mkdir -p "${LAUNCH_PATH}"
    #WORKDIR "${REPO_PATH}"
    WORKDIR /code
    #COPY --from=dt-car-interface ${CATKIN_WS_DIR}/src/dt-car-interface ${CATKIN_WS_DIR}/src/dt-car-interface
    
    # keep some arguments as environment variables
    ENV DT_MODULE_TYPE "${REPO_NAME}"
    ENV DT_MODULE_DESCRIPTION "${DESCRIPTION}"
    ENV DT_MODULE_ICON "${ICON}"
    ENV DT_MAINTAINER "${MAINTAINER}"
    ENV DT_REPO_PATH "${REPO_PATH}"
    ENV DT_LAUNCH_PATH "${LAUNCH_PATH}"
    ENV DT_LAUNCHER "${LAUNCHER}"
    
    # Daniel - Add some dependencies
    RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
             gcc \
             libc-dev\
             git \
             bzip2 \
             python3-tk \
             python3-wheel \
             python3-pip  \
             python3-pillow  \
             software-properties-common \
             #Pytorch dependencies
             libopenblas-dev \
             libblas-dev \
             libcairo2-dev \
             pkg-config \
             m4 \
             cmake \
             cython \
             python3-dev \
             python3-yaml \
             curl \
             python3-setuptools && \
         rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
    RUN echo PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH
    RUN pip3 install -U "pip>=20.2" pipdeptree setuptools wheel
    RUN pip3 install pycairo
    COPY ./libraries "${REPO_PATH}/libraries"
    RUN pip3 install "${REPO_PATH}/libraries/numpy-1.20.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl"
    RUN pip3 install "${REPO_PATH}/libraries/torch-2.1.0a0+41361538.nv23.06-cp38-cp38-linux_aarch64.whl"
    RUN pip3 install "${REPO_PATH}/libraries/torchvision-0.19.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl"
    
    RUN pipdeptree
    RUN pip list
    
    RUN echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list && \
        curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
        sudo apt-get update && \
        sudo apt-get install libedgetpu1-std
    
    
    # install apt dependencies
    COPY ./dependencies-apt.txt "${REPO_PATH}/"
    RUN dt-apt-install ${REPO_PATH}/dependencies-apt.txt
    
    # install python3 dependencies
    COPY ./dependencies-py3.txt "${REPO_PATH}/"
    RUN pip3 install -r ${REPO_PATH}/dependencies-py3.txt
    
    # copy the source code
    COPY ./packages "${REPO_PATH}/packages"
    
    # build packages
    RUN . /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh && \
      catkin build \
        --workspace ${CATKIN_WS_DIR}/
    
    # install launcher scripts
    COPY ./launchers/. "${LAUNCH_PATH}/"
    COPY ./launchers/default.sh "${LAUNCH_PATH}/"
    RUN dt-install-launchers "${LAUNCH_PATH}"
    
    # define default command
    CMD ["bash", "-c", "dt-launcher-${DT_LAUNCHER}"]
    
    # store module metadata
    LABEL org.duckietown.label.module.type="${REPO_NAME}" \
        org.duckietown.label.module.description="${DESCRIPTION}" \
        org.duckietown.label.module.icon="${ICON}" \
        org.duckietown.label.architecture="${ARCH}" \
        org.duckietown.label.code.location="${REPO_PATH}" \
        org.duckietown.label.code.version.distro="${DISTRO}" \
        org.duckietown.label.base.image="${BASE_IMAGE}" \
        org.duckietown.label.base.tag="${BASE_TAG}" \
        org.duckietown.label.maintainer="${MAINTAINER}"
    # <== Do not change the code above this line
    # <==================================================

here is the dockerfile as attached. please let me know if any other modification is needed. I am using nvidia jetson neno - 4GB with jetpack version 4.4

Please provide the Dockerfile.

dockerfile provided.

Is the dockerfile looks ok?

How are you running your container after building the image? did you try using the --privileged flag while firing up the container?

Does this 'so' file libgomp-804f19d4.so.1.0.0 reside in your host machine? if yes then try to pre-load it while building the container image. e.g ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ libgomp-804f19d4.so.1.0.0.
